# Calculate html table cell width using css calc() function with percentage and fixed size such as px, rem

Tags: html, css, sass, html-table

I'm wondering if it is possible to use calc() together with percentage and a fixed value to dynamically calculate width of html table cells? Lets say that I would like first and third column to be 10rem, second column 70%, fourth column 30% of the remaining width after subtracting the width for the fixed first and third columns. The table should not have a fixed with but use all available width of the parent container.

It is possible to set width to auto for the second column and set fourth column to a percentage.

[CodePen eaxample](https://codepen.io/sanjaco/pen/ExKGBmj)

**SCSS code**

```
body {
  padding: .5rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.title {
  margin-bottom: .2rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.container {
  width:100%;
}

.div1 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
  
  div {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #5DADE2;
    margin-left: .1rem;
    margin-top: .1rem;
    margin-bottom: .1rem;
    
    &:nth-of-type(1){
      width:auto;
      width:10rem;
      background-color: #AED6F1;
    }
    
    &:nth-of-type(3){
      width:auto;
      width:10rem;
      background-color: #AED6F1;
    }
    
     &:nth-of-type(2){
      width:auto;
      width: unquote("calc((100% - 20rem - 1rem) * .7)");
    }
    
    &:nth-of-type(4){
      width:auto;
      width: unquote("calc((100% - 20rem - 2rem) * .3)"); 
    }
    
    &:last-of-type {
      margin-right: .1rem;
    }
  }
}

.table1 {
  background-color: #D6EAF8;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
}

thead {
  tr {
    background-color: #5DADE2;
 }
}

tbody {
  td {
    text-align:center;
  }
}

table {
  .col1, .col3 {
    width: 10rem;
  }

  .col2 {
    width: auto;
    //width: unquote("calc(70% - 20rem)");
    width: unquote("calc((100% - 20rem - 1rem) * .7)"); // Does not work
  }

  .col4 {
    width:auto;
    width: unquote("calc((100% - 20rem - 2rem) * .3)"); // Does not work
    //width: unquote("calc(30% - 20rem)"); // Does not work
    //width: unquote("calc(30% - 20rem);"); // Does not work
    //width: calc(30% - 20rem); // Does not work
    //width: calc(30% - (20rem)); // Does not work
    //width: calc(20rem); // Works
    //width: calc(20rem); // Works
  }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2 class="title">Dynamically calculate table cell width</h2>
    
    <h2 class="title">Not a real example. Just trying out calc</h2>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="div1">
      <div class="col1">Val 1</div>
      <div class="col2">Val 2</div>
      <div class="col3">Val 3</div>
      <div class="col4">Val 4</div>
    </div>
      
      <h2 class="title">Table</h2>
      <table class="table1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="col1">Col 1</th>
            <th class="col2">Col 2</th>
            <th class="col3">Col 3</th>
            <th class="col4">Col 4</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="col1">Val 1</td>
            <td class="col2">Val 2</td>
            <td class="col3">Col 3</td>
            <td class="col4">Col 4</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `SCSS` not run this snippet. You can change to code only.

Comment: Try `calc(#{"30% - 20rem"})`

Comment: SCSS interpolation does not seem to make any difference. See updated CodePen example. I did try it before, however with SCSS variables, to ensure that the calculation occurred at runtime and not at compile time? I missed to include this test in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can use `calc()` to do what you've mentioned. Here's how you can do it.

scss

```
.col1, .col3 {
   width: 10rem;
 }

 .col2 {
   --remainingWidth: calc(100% - 20rem);
   width: calc(var(--remainingWidth) * 0.7);
 }

 .col4 {
   --remainingWidth: calc(100% - 20rem);
   width: calc(var(--remainingWidth) * 0.3);
 }
```

Comment: I tried CSS custom properties. However, I did not notice any difference. See updated CodePen example. Perhaps I have missed something?